# Docker cross compile build context leads to `dockerfile.v0: unsupported frontend capability moby.buildkit.frontend.contexts`

Tags: docker, arm

I'm trying to cross compile a rust application for my raspberry pi (the compilation there is very slow).
For that I try to execute a Dockerfile with a build context somewhere else (because there are some certificates and other things, which are needed in the Docker image).

Dockerfile (./myapp/Dockerfile)

```
FROM rust

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pkg-config libssl-dev build-essential cmake
WORKDIR /home/myapp
COPY --from=local ./myapp/. .
COPY --from=local ./mqtt-helper/ /home/mqtt-helper/

COPY --from=local ./mqtt-broker/config/certs/ca.crt ./certs/
COPY --from=local ./mqtt-broker/config/certs/mqtt-subscriber.key ./certs/
COPY --from=local ./mqtt-broker/config/certs/mqtt-subscriber.crt ./certs/

ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN cargo install --path .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["myapp"]
```

Now I'm trying to run:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 --build-context local=./ ./myapp/
```

But this call always leads into:

```bash
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: unsupported frontend capability moby.buildkit.frontend.contexts
```

thank you

Comment: I have the issue on Ubuntu Linux and Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f. Would be interested when you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/) you need to use Dockerfile version 1.4 or later as a Dockerfile frontend to use multiple build contexts. It seems that the frontend bundled with your current setup does not yet support this feature. Try putting the following [parser directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#syntax) at the top of your `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
```

This should automatically download the `docker/dockerfile:1.4` image and use it as a custom Dockerfile frontend instead of the frontend bundled with your system. See [Custom Dockerfile syntax](https://docs.docker.com/build/dockerfile/frontend/) for more details.